# Mongodb and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

I am using an implementation of devise on a mongo database. I need a dropdown menu tu appear in my sign up view so I added the following line:

```
<%= f.select :status, options_for_select(["Viewer", "Standard", "Tutor"])%>
```

I also added to the user.rb model:

```
field :status, :type => String, :default => ""
```

But when I check the database, the status field appears empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= f.select :status, [["Viewer","Viewer"], ["Standard","Standard"], ["Tutor","Tutor"]], { :include_blank => "Please select" }  %>
```